# ELASTIC_PASSWORD_FILE is not working in Kibana container

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I have tried use ELASTIC_PASSWORD_FILE in Kibana container under environment. However, it seeems like it cant read the value. Any suggestion?

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.14.0
    secrets:
      - es_password
    environment:
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=/run/secrets/es_password
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./kibana.yml
        target: /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml

secrets:
  es_password:
    file: ./.password
```

kibana.yml

```
elasticsearch.password: '${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}'
```

Comment: Please share some logs, your dockerfile and your compose yaml file at least.

Comment: Hi i have shared the respective files

Comment: is /run/secrets/es_password a file path or the actual password?

Comment: it is path to actual password. i echo after docker exec , the value appearing. docker exec -it kibana bash then echo ELASTIC_PASSWORD, value appearing

Comment: i also removed /run'secrets/es_password  and hard code the password still not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to set xpack.security.enabled as "true" env variable as well.

Like this:

```
environment:
      xpack.security.enabled: "true"
      ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD: <your_password>
```

More info on this here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-set-passwords-for-built-in-users-with-docker-compose-setup/198096/3

Comment: hi, still same reason: missing authentication credentials for REST request. if i hardcode no issue. if use environment having issue. Unleass i hadcode value in ibana.yml, then it working

Comment: when you echo with docker exec, what output do you get?

Comment: i get the password when i echo $ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD

Comment: In that case, try removing the single quotes ' in your kibana.yml file

Comment: elasticsearch.username: 'elastic'

elasticsearch.password: $ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD

i tried this but still not working

Comment: but if i hardcode the $ELASTIC_PASSWORD, it is working fine

Comment: i tried echo $ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD also not working

Comment: Okay, then maybe you need to mount the /run/secrets/es_password file too

Comment: If it cat /run/secrets/es_password inside my container it appears the value. i using docker-compsoe secrets

Comment: I tired ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=myP@ssword also not working even i hard code in docker compsoe

Comment: But earlier you said that when you hard-coded the $ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD it was working.

Comment: what i did is, i removed the container and start again it was working.  ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD= mypassword. however if i do  ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD} not working. to be honest quite confusing what the issue

Comment: elasticsearch i use environment variable no issue. issue only to kibana.

Comment: And what happens when you hardcode Kibana password? Does that work?

Comment: In which file did you apply the edits I recommend in my answer? Those are for kibana.yml - try those - also aa per kibana documentation, it's not mentioned anywhere fhat you can mention password file path instead of your password in the compose file.